# limit of a sequence along ultrafilter

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

If $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff topological space,$(x_n)_{n}$ is a sequence in $X$, for any ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ on $\mathbb{N}$, I know the fact that $\lim_{\mathcal{F}}x_n$ exists and is unique.

I think that the limit may be different for two different ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$. Can anyone show me some examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\mathcal{F}_m$ is the principal ultrafilter corresponding to $m\in\mathbb{N}$, then the limit of $(x_n)$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}_m$ is just $x_m$.  So any sequence which is not constant gives an example.

A little less trivially, there are also easy examples with nontrivial ultrafilters.  For instance, let $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ be two sequences in $X$ which converge to distinct points $y$ and $z$, respectively.  Let $x_{2n}=y_n$ and $x_{2n+1}=z_n$.  Then for any nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ which contains the even numbers, the limit of $(x_n)$ with respect to $\mathcal{F}$ will be $y$, while for any nonprincipal ultrafilter $\mathcal{F}$ which contains the odd nubmers, the limit of $(x_n)$ with respct to $\mathcal{F}$ will be $z$.

More generally, if $(x_n)$ is any sequence, then every accumulation point is the limit of $x_n$ with respect to some nonprincipal ultrafilter.  So, if $(x_n)$ has more than one accumulation point, this gives nonprincipal ultrafilters for which it has different limits.

Comment: One should perhaps point out that $\beta\Bbb N$ is a compact Hausdorff space that has a sequence that has $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ accumulation points. And of course $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is a countable sequence in $[0,1]$ with $2^{\aleph_0}$ accumulation points.

Comment: If the sequence $ (x_n)$ has only one accumulation point,for different free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, the limit has only one value.Is that true?@Eric Wofsey

Comment: @Asaf Karagila,if $(x_n)=\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$,then there exist $2^{\aleph_0}$ free filters on $\mathbb{N}$ such that each limit is different.Is that correct?

Comment: @mathrookie: Yes. For each $r\in[0,1]$ choose a sequence of rationals which converges to it (e.g. cut the decimal expansion of $r$). Now enumerate the rationals as $q_n$, and take an ultrafilter which contains the indices of the sequence converging to $r$.

Comment: @mathrookie: Yes, if $(x_n)$ has only one accumulation point, then that accumulation point must actually be its limit as a sequence (assuming your space is compact).  So, it is also the limit with respect to every nonprincipal ultrafilter.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey,I have another question.If we know that $0$ is not an acculation point of $(x_n)$ ,can we conclude that $lim_{\mathcal{F}}x_n\neq 0$ for any free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$?

Comment: Yes, that is pretty much immediate from the definitions.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey,would you mind explaing it indetails?Thanks